# OpenVPN: Options error: Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s)

Tags: linux, centos, vpn, openvpn

I am trying to assign different ip address ranges to two different types of users of `OpenVPN`.  The two user types are `administrators` and `employees`.  Towards this end, I created certificates and keys for `employees` and `administrators`, and then I created a separate `.ovpn` file for each instead of using `client.ovpn`.  The problem is that OpenVPN does not seem to like to syntax of my `.ovpn` files.

Specifically, when I type `openvpn --config /path/to/administrators.ovpn` into the CentOS 7 terminal at the CLIENT computer, I get the following error message:

```
Options error: Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s)  
in /path/to/administrators.ovpn:1: administrators (2.3.6)
```

Here are my file contents:

On the remote CentOS 7 SERVER, my `server.conf` is:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
client-config-dir ccd
route 10.8.1.0 255.255.255.0
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nobody
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

Also on the remote SERVER `/etc/openvpn/ccd/administrators` is:

```
ifconfig-push 10.8.1.1 10.8.1.2
```

On the CLIENT, my `/path/to/administrators.ovpn` is:

```
administrators
dev tun
proto udp
remote server.ip.addr 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
comp-lzo
verb 3
ca /path/to/ca.crt
cert /path/to/administrators.crt
key /path/to/administrators.key
```

I get the same error now for `employees.ovpn`, and also if I rename either file `client.ovpn`.

**How can I resolve this error so that a connection is made over OpenVPN?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at that first line on:

```
/path/to/administrators.ovpn

administrators  <====
```

Get rid of it.  Thats is not an openvpn parameter.

**UPDATE**

Yes, I see you needed to add the client parameter as well.  I am in the habit of setting up OpenVPN between networks with static keys and IP addresses.  I never need the client parameter in those cases.

Comment: Getting rid of `administrators` did not solve the problem.  However, replacing `administrators` with `client` did solve the problem.  You were close.  I will mark this as the answer, assuming that readers will read this comment to see what needs to change.